# Evaluating ToggleButton on specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I evaluate the status of a toggle button on a specific worksheet?

If my code is stored with the specific worksheet, I can just refer to the name of the button:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    Debug.Print "true"
Else
    Debug.Print "false"
End If
End Sub
```

However, if my code is stored in a module the above method does not worked. I have tried the following but it also does not work:

```
Public Sub Check_Button()
If Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("ToggleButton1").Value = True Then
    Debug.Print "true"
Else
    Debug.Print "false"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
Public Sub Check_Button()
If Sheets("sheet1").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    Debug.Print "true"
Else
    Debug.Print "false"
End If
End Sub
```

And whilst it's probably not good practice it's worth mentioning you can lose the `".Value"` as such:

```
If Sheets("sheet1").ToggleButton1 = True Then
```